Sup panel thoughts
I want to run a sub panel to a shed like 50 ft not gonna have a lot of connected just a mini split air con couple of lights Ang plugs for like tv n ps5 nothing big  what size of wire I should run???

What does the minisplit require ?  That should be on a circuit itself.

As you are planning to install a subpanel, don't just look at what you want to use now, but also consider what loads you might want to add in the next decade or two.

The wire size is determined by the breaker size that feeds the sub panel.  The breaker size is determined by doing a load calculation on the main panel to see how much power/amps you can use for the sub panel.  This could be as little as 20 amps to over a 100 amps depending on how much power you use in the house.

Welcome to DIY.SE! Please use proper sentences, capitalization, punctuation, and spelling. These will make your question easier to understand.
